# Using Auto Layout with Dynamic UITextView, UIImageView, and UILabel Heights

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitextview, xcode5, autolayout

I am trying to create a view that contains one image view with 2 labels and text views.  The contents of each element will be read in from an SQLite database, so I would like to use Xcode 5's auto layout to change the heights of each UI element and the distance between them based on the content of each to use the screen space as efficiently as possible.  I have a few conditions that I am trying to enforce via auto layout in the interface builder, but I am not sure how to implement them:

- The distance between a label and the text view directly below it will stay the same
- The widths of all elements will stay the same and they will all be centered horizontally
- Only heights and y values of the elements' frames will change
- If the content heights of the text views exceed the amount of screen height they can be displayed in, the image view's height should be decreased to a minimum value, then the heights of the text views should be decreased
- The distance between each element should be equal (excluding distances between associated labels and text views)

I would be able to do all of this programmatically, but I would like to use the auto layout so the view can easily adapt to changes in screen size and to prevent bugs.  I have very little experience with auto layout and I am having trouble with the complex specifications I need in this situation.  To make what I intend to create clearer, here is a screenshot of the .xib file:

[image: screenshot]

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 5):

http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/Implementing_iOS_6_Auto_Layout_Constraints_in_Code

please reffer this website,
may be got your solution

Answer (score 0):

Take a look [Autolayout Visual Format Language](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/VisualFormatLanguage/VisualFormatLanguage.html).  They talk about this in a few of the auto layout WWDC videos from last year.

This isn't complete, but you will need to define the constraints both vertically and horizontally.  This is complete but hopefully gives you a ruff idea to get your started.

```
 // Vertical alignment should be centered
 NSArray *constraints = [NSLayoutConstraint
  constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|[_imageView]-[_label1]-[_textBlock1]-[label2]-[textBlock2]-|"
                      options:NSLayoutFormatAlignAllCenterY
                      metrics:nil
                      views:viewsDictionary];

// Tell the views/text blocks to take the entire width. The labels will be fine centered on them I think
NSArray *constraints = [NSLayoutConstraint
  constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|-[_imageView]-|"
                      options:NSLayoutFormatAlignAllCenterY
                      metrics:nil
                      views:viewsDictionary];

NSArray *constraints = [NSLayoutConstraint
  constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|-[_textBlock1]-|"
                      options:nil
                      metrics:nil
                      views:viewsDictionary];

NSArray *constraints = [NSLayoutConstraint
  constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|-[_textBlock2]-|"
                      options:nil
                      metrics:nil
                      views:viewsDictionary];
```